# fabricjs fix rotate corner Icon

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have this problem with fabricjs1.5 I have changed the default control corners to display a custom corner icon, but in 1.4 it works fine but with 1.5 when I scale the object the corners scale too??

also can I bind scale to the rotate handle corner??

please have a look at the fiddle and see what I mean.

```js
isVML = function() {
  return typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== 'undefined';
};

fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
  hasRotatingPoint: true,
  cornerSize: 40,
  _drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
    if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
      return;
    }
    var size = this.cornerSize,
      size2 = size / 2,
      scaleOffsetY = size2 / this.scaleY,
      scaleOffsetX = size2 / this.scaleX,
      height = this.height,
      width = this.width
      // left = (this.width / 2),
      //  top = (this.height / 2)

    isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size / this.scaleX, size / this.scaleY);

    if (control !== 'br')
      ctx['fillRect'](left, top, size / this.scaleX, size / this.scaleY);

    var SelectedIconImage = new Image();
    if (control === 'br') {
      SelectedIconImage.src = 'http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/56/56433.svg';

      ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, size / this.scaleX, size / this.scaleY);

      this.setControlsVisibility({
        bl: false,
        br: true,
        tl: true,
        tr: false,
        mt: false,
        mb: false,
        ml: false,
        mr: false,
        mtr: false,
      });

    }

 
  }
 

});

degreesToRadians = fabric.util.degreesToRadians;
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Canvas.prototype, {
  setCursor: function(value) {
    this.upperCanvasEl.style.cursor = value;
  },
  _getActionFromCorner: function(target, corner) {
    var action = 'drag';
    if (corner) {
      action = (corner === 'ml' || corner === 'mr') ? 'scaleX' : (corner === 'mt' || corner === 'mb') ? 'scaleY' : (corner === 'mtr' || corner === 'br') ? 'rotate' : 'scale';
    }
    return action;
  },
  _setCornerCursor: function(corner, target) {
    if ((corner === 'mtr' || corner === 'br') && target.hasRotatingPoint) {
      this.setCursor(this.rotationCursor);
    } else if (corner in cursorOffset) {
      this.setCursor(this._getRotatedCornerCursor(corner, target));
    } else {
      this.setCursor(this.defaultCursor);
      return false;
    }
  }

});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
}));
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px" style="border:1px solid gray"></canvas>
```

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimjan/2XZHp/113/

Comment: Thank you for that, that did the trick, my second question was can I bind the scale handle to the rotate handle corner??

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer:
[Fabric js custom rotate icon is not visible in only iphone's google chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352604/fabric-js-custom-rotate-icon-is-not-visible-in-only-iphones-google-chrome-brows)

Here is opposite, with 1.4.0 is scaling controls, 1.5.0 is not.
There is some internal difference in the library, and there you find correct one for 1.5.0 ( to adapt to your needs ).
Check that you are reloading the image every frame draw. In that answer we are discussing also that.

To fix your problem:

```
ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, size / this.scaleX, size / this.scaleY);
```

remove scale factor from here

```
ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, size, size);
```

Comment: uh i did not notice that, i checj

Comment: ok so I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimjan/2XZHp/120/ but still can't get to bind the scale to the rotate handel ?? any help is apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed it thanx to AndreaBogazzi, have a look at the updated fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimjan/2XZHp/125/

but I am still struggling with binding scale and rotate on the same corner as I have said in my original post??

```
    _getActionFromCorner: function(target, corner) {

   if (corner && corner === 'br') {
        var action_rotate = (target) ? 'rotate' : 'rotate'
        var action_scale = (target) ? 'scale' : 'scale'
        return action_rotate;
    }
```

}

I want action_rotate and action_scale to work together on the same corner ?? any thoughts